# solve equilibrium points and the equation from given derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question shows this:

> $$
>     \frac{dN}{dt} = \frac{1}{4} N(t) \left( 1 - \frac{N(t)}{225}\right) - \frac{7}{2}
> $$

How can we solve the equation as we don't know what is the power of t present in the function N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little bit of arithmetic we can rewrite the equation as
$$
    \frac{dN}{dt} = -\frac{N^2 - 225N + 3150}{900}
$$
Where $N$ is just shorthand for $N(t)$.

The question title asks about *equilibrium points*.  Those are the constant solutions to this differential equation.  If $N(t)$ is constant, $\frac{dN}{dt} = 0$.  This is equivalent to
$$
    N^2 - 225N+3150 = 0 \implies (N-15)(N-210) = 0
$$
So there are two equilibria: $N(t) \equiv 15$ and $N(t) \equiv 210$.

In the question you wondered how to solve for $N(t)$ “when we don't know the power of $t$ present in $N$.”  Differential equations are, in general, hard to solve.  There's no guarantee that $N(t)$ is a power function to begin with.  But notice that we found the equilibria without finding $N(t)$ explicitly.  In DE you can say a lot *about* the solutions without knowing their closed-form expression.

As it turns out, this DE is what we call *separable* and can be solved explicitly.  We write
$$
    \frac{dN}{(N-15)(N-210)} = - \frac{1}{900} \,dt
    \implies
    \int\frac{dN}{(N-15)(N-210)} = - \int\frac{1}{900} \,dt
$$
At first blush, this looks like voodoo math but it is grounded in rigor.  In any case, the right-hand side is easily integrated but the left-hand side requires partial fractions:
$$
\frac{1}{(N-15)(N-210)} = \frac{1}{195}\left(\frac{1}{N-210} - \frac{1}{N-15}\right) 
$$
Moving the constant to the other side, we now have
$$
    \int\left(\frac{1}{N-210} - \frac{1}{N-15}\right)\,dN
= -\int\frac{195}{900}\,dt = - \int \frac{13}{60} \,dt
$$
Now we can integrate!
$$
    \ln\left|\frac{N-210}{N-15}\right| = -\frac{13t}{60} + C
$$
where $C$ is some constant depending on the initial conditions of $N(t)$.
Exponentiating,
$$
    \frac{N-210}{N-15} = e^{-13t/60 + C} = e^C e^{-13t/60} = C_1   e^{-13t/60} 
$$
This can be solved for $N$ in terms of $t$:
\begin{align*}
    N-210 &= C_1 e^{-13t/60}(N-15)\\\implies
    e^{13t/60}N - 210 e^{13t/60} &= C_1 N - 15 C_1 \\\implies
    N\left(e^{13t/60}-C_1\right) &= 210 e^{13t/60}- 15 C_1 \\\implies
    N(t) &= \frac{210 e^{13t/60}- 15 C_1}{e^{13t/60}-C_1}
\end{align*}
(acknowledgements to [Wolfram Alpha](http://bit.ly/2cOeHG3))

Now that we have the explicit form for $N(t)$, notice that
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{t\to+\infty} N(t) &= 210 \\
    \lim_{t\to-\infty} N(t) &= 15
\end{align*}
and these are our two equilibrium solutions.  This means 210 is a stable equilibrium and 15 is unstable.  But again, most of the question can be answered *without* solving the equation explicitly.

Comment: When solving the de, where does the -1/900 come from? Since the dN/dt is factorised into (N-210)(N-15). Shouldn't it be 1dt instead of -1/900dt?

Comment: @user365442: $dN/dt$ is factorised into $(N-210)(N-15)\color{red}{(-1/900)}$.  The constant factor of $-1/900$ doesn't affect the solutions to $dN/dt\equiv 0$, but it does affect the explicit $N(t)$.